# Omitir serialización de valores nulos

Tags: c#

Estoy serializando una estructura de objetos bastante grande en C#. Puedo serializarlo sin problemas, pero me piden que las propiedades que no tienen valor los omita.

El problema es que cuando alguna propiedad es nula no pone valor, pero si aparece en el xml resultante. He visto que hay una posibilidad usando `ShouldSerialized{nombre_propiedad}` tal y como indica aquí https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/53b8022e(v=vs.110).aspx. Lo malo de esta solución es que tiene que ser propiedad a propiedad y, como he comentado antes, la estructura del objeto a serializar es bastante grande y buscaba algo que me permitiese omitir todos los nulos de golpe.

Muchas gracias por adelantado por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Si utilizas Json.Net (lo cual te recomiendo) puedes usar `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` para evitar serializar las propiedades nulas. Mira [aqui (en ingles)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6507889/579895)

Comment: Hola @pikoh, no lo había pensado. El caso es que para enviar datos a otro proveedor estoy usando Json.Net para generar un json pero no había caído en usarlo para serializar a XML. Muchas gracias. Lo probaré.

Comment: Perdona, pero asumí que la serialización la hacias a JSON (fallo mio, no lei correctamente la pregunta). Para XML no te sirve Json.Net

Comment: De todas maneras, creo que por defecto `XmlSerializer` no serializa las propiedades que están a `null`, asi que quizá lo que yo haría sería,antes de serializar, poner a null todas las propiedades que esten vacias

Comment: Según la documentación (que yo no lo sabía) Json.Net si serializa XML (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertJsonToXml.htm). Lo probaré y ya te contaré. XmlSerializer si me serializa las propiedades nulas así "<mipropiedad />".

Comment: Pues yo tampoco lo sabía. Espero que con Json.Net soluciones el problema :)

Comment: hey bro! ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: No, al final no pude resolverlo.